# java: ObjectInputStream gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, sockets, object, tcp, nullpointerexception

Server side

```
ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = null;
objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream());
```

Client side

```
ObjectInputStream objectInput = null;
objectInput= new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());//here is the problem
```

Server works good. but at the client side where the`objectInput= new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());` is , i get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`
What is wrong?

Comment: Is clientSocket actually connected?

Comment: @ControlAltDel yes, first i make the connection and then i create the streams

Comment: According to the docs, nullpointerexception means that clientSocket.getInputStream() is null: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html

Comment: Could you show us your client code where you establish the socket connection in relation to where you access the streams? Also post the entire StackTrace of the NPE please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My *guess* is that somehow, your socket or inputstream is closed before you add the ObjectInputStream. This could *easily* happen if after establishing the connection on the server side, the socket isn't stored somewhere it can be retrieved outside of the method in which you created it. In this case, the socket would be out of scope, the object will get disposed, and the stream will close.

You haven't posted very much code, but this would be my default guess (having worked a lot with java.net.Socket) as to what it going on